# Adding components in UITextView

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitextview

I'm not sure if this is a best practice or not but it will be great if I can get some suggestion on that.

I have a UIViewController in Storyboard that has UITextview and I'm adding two UILabels inside that UITextView then via code appending AttributtedStrings into UILabels.

When I run it I can see the my dynamic text in those labels but when I try scroll UITextView it doesn't scroll labels but if I append text directly to UITextView it scrolls.

Comment: Any specific reason you are using a text view as a container? Can you use. UIView? And if you are looking for scroll you could use a scroll view.

Comment: I can use UIView and add that into scrollview or else I can use tableview as well but I was wondering if this is possible this way.

Comment: You could, but I would advice against it. UITextfield is designed to hold text. It would be he hard to predict how it would behave if you embed other views inside it.

Comment: Thanks @TheAppMentor yeah you're right and I don't want to go for bad practice so I will create a tableview or scrollview. Thanks